# How to go from a MVC view to a section of another view without the hash in URL

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an issue in MVC to go with anchor from one view to a section in another view without the hash in the URL to be displayed. I am navigating in my Controler's views like normal /news or /test, but I want to go to a section of the Index view and I am doing it with /#contact. I have tried to javascript it and remove it from the visual URL with the following solution:

```
window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))
```

and this:

```
history.pushState(obj, title, url);
```

But this is not helping, because the URL is not updating at the time of the first click. I tried to delay the event with some ms, but it is not pro at all... Can you give me some advices or hints to remove #contact from the URL and still be on the section "contact" of the View.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery hash to alter URL without bookmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613027/using-jquery-hash-to-alter-url-without-bookmarking) or if you are using js, why not prevent the default action of the link and then scroll to the position of the element with the id

Comment: There are many other parameters than the href in window.location. See full reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

What you are looking for as a starter might be the window.location.hostname, have you tried it?

Comment: @Pete I tried event.preventDefault() that is executed by the click method of the anchor and after that scrolling to the section, but the js is executing before the Index page is loaded and it don't find the element to scroll to. May be a part of the whole issue is firing js by click event from one view and executing it when the anchor view is loaded. This may sounds confusing, but I am new at MVC and js. 10x for further hints.